# memoir: indentation after enumerate in footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes, memoir, enumerate, enumitem

I have a footnote that contains an enumeration, after which comes one or two lines of text. The lines after the enumeration look "off", and I would like them indented to the same spot as the lines before the enumeration, ie. *These* and *According* should be aligned vertically (see red and blue lines in the image).

I have tried experimenting with a `\hspace`, but I can't seem to find the correct length to insert...

[image: example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

%%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

Paragraph talking about some person.\footnote{These are their likely children:{\scriptsize
\begin{enumerate}[a), labelindent=1cm, leftmargin=*]
\item \emph{John Doe}, who did this and that;
\item \emph{Jane Doe}, who did other things;
\item Possibly \emph{Jack Doe} who became known elsewhere.
\end{enumerate}}%
%\hspace*{???}%
According to a certain source, they had 5 children of which two are thus unknown.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with lists. If you write normal text, you'll also notice that line two an onwards matches the left edge of the text. Only the first line id indented in a footnote.

Comment: Ah. Well, I would still like it indented. `\footparindent` is slightly too much to my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can play with. This setup is one that I often use in the books I design. Note that we use `\scriptsize` for the footnotes instead of `\footnotesize` (not that it matters)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% sample text
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength\footmarkwidth{1em}
\setlength\footmarksep{0em}
\setlength\footparindent{1.5em}
\addtolength\footnotesep{2pt}
%\footmarkstyle{\textsuperscript{#1}\hphantom{\textsuperscript{9}}}
\footmarkstyle{\textsuperscript{#1}\hspace{0.25em}}
%\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{10pt}
\renewcommand\foottextfont{\scriptsize}%\RaggedRight}
\renewcommand*\footfudgefiddle{80}

\begin{document}

Paragraph talking about some person.\footnote{These are their likely children:
\begin{enumerate}[(a),,noitemsep]
\item \emph{John Doe}, who did this and that;
\item \emph{Jane Doe}, who did other things;
\item Possibly \emph{Jack Doe} who became known elsewhere.
\end{enumerate}
According to a certain source, they had 5 children of which two are
thus unknown.}

Test\footnote{\kant[1]}


\end{document}
```